# REST API endpoint to validate frontend entity

Tags: rest, api, validation, endpoint

We are designing a REST API for our application. On our frontend we have a billing information form that submits to the following endpoint: `POST /billing-information`. However, we need some validation before being able to submit the form.

Some validations are easy (e.g.: input length, allowed characters) and are directly performed on the frontend via JS. Other validations are more complicated and require some database interaction. Our business flow requires we perform these validations before the form is submitted.

My question is, what would be a RESTful API endpoint to perform such validation on billing information? We thought about `POST /billing-information/validate` but it doesn't look that much in the sense of REST APIs. What are the best practices in this direction?

Comment: Why don't you have your validation in same webservice. Before submitting billling information check all validation if any of information is incorrect do not proceed ahead and return the validation failed error.

Comment: We follow same structure while developing webservice. As we receive request we send it to request validator. This request validator will check for both logical and business required data in request. If any of data is missing and it is mandatory field for that request to be fullfilled then we return saying it as 'Bad Request'

Comment: Validation is performed in the same web service, just that we could not come up with a RESTful endpoint naming for it. Not sure I understood your point.

Comment: Your endpoint will be : POST /billing-information . Only Validation will be done before saving the details into database or before performing any business logic into it. Hope we both are on same track .

Comment: That will also happen, but our business logic requires the validation happens before the user clicks the submit button.

Answer (score 1):

In the most cases the best practise would be to **be pragmatic**.

The idea is not to follow `REST` blindly, right? Especially if we talk about our own UI or webservice as a consumer. If you expect that your `validate` endpoint will be used by external clients, ok, you may want to look a bit better in eyes of your customers (if they are 100% REST fanatics), by providing the following endpoint:

```
POST api/billing-information-drafts
```

`POST` to this collection causes all backend validations to happen but nothing is stored. It is worth to emphasize that your `api/billing-information` enpoint should perform the same validations anyway to make sure you will not violate business rules.

Comment: Being pragmatic was the obvious choice for us as well, but I wanted to figure what would be the _right_ way to tackle this endpoint.